# Linear algebra, dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of dimension $7$ and let $f: V \to R$ be a non zero linear functional. Let $W$ be a linear subspace of $V$ such that $V = \operatorname{ker}(f)$ direct sum $W$ , where $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is the null space of $f$. What is dimension of $W$?  Answer: $\operatorname{dim} W = 1$ , how to find . please help

Comment: [Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

$\dim W=rank(f)=\dim(Im(f))$ , because $f_{|W} : W \to Im(f)$ is isomorphic and since $Imf \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is non zero then 
$1\leq \dim(Im(f)) \leq \dim(\mathbb{R})=1$ hence $\dim(W)=\dim(Im(f))=1$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Prove that $f $is surjective and conclude that $7 = \dim \ker f + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the given data:

$$dim V = dim ker f + dim W$$

By the theorem:

$$dim V = rank f + nullity f$$

But by the definition nullity $f = dim ker f$ so we have $dim W = rank f$. By the definition $rank f = dim R$ (i.e) no.of.element in the basis of R. Basis of $R = \{1\}$. Hence $dim W = 1$

Comment: Hi, welcome on the MathSE! Note, this site supports Latex, just type in `$5\cdot 5$` and you get $5\cdot 5$. Partially I edited your post, I suggest to do the rest.